# A simple way to explain Abel's impossibility theorem

Tags: group-theory

For philosophy students, I want to explain very briefly the theory of equations showing the very great innovations in thinking made by Abel (the study of them as structure), and Galois (the resolvability of their ambiguity as a dynamic reciprocal determination) (Deleuze), for which I need to explain first some rudiments of both theories, and it occurred to me that, in summary, it could be as follows:

- Operations with roots create indeterminate multi-valued results which, in the case of roots of positive numbers were known as "surd" (absurdities) for a long time, and in those of negative ones, the imaginary numbers they give rise to were doubtful even to Euler and Gauss. In the first case it is solved because the real numbers form an ordered set, while in the second they do not.
- The complex numbers always occur as conjugate pairs so there are no individual imaginary numbers and, by the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra, an equation of odd degree can only have an even number of imaginary solutions and an odd number of real solutions (as in the cubics).
- So, in principle, a quintic could only have 5 real roots, or 1 conjugate pair and three real, or 2 imaginary pairs and one real but Kronecker, by a result derived from Abel and Galois, showed that a polynomial with an odd prime degree is only reducible to a field extension if it has only one real root and the others complex or, if all its roots are real.
- The result is that in a quintic the group S5, which would correspond to that of an icosahedron, is not solvable and only those that present partial symmetries as i.e.: the dihedral D5 group of the pentagon are solvable, which only those that have a very particular relation between their coefficients fulfill (Spearman & Williams, Characterization of Solvable Quintics $x^5 + ax + b$, [https://people.math.carleton.ca/~williams/papers/pdf/185.pdf](https://people.math.carleton.ca/%7Ewilliams/papers/pdf/185.pdf). And, as a consequence, there is no general formula for every quintic involving nested radicals.
  Is this presentation correct?
  Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is good as an overview for philosophy students (I think you need not go into deeper details) and I would consider it to be correct. Note that the polynomial is usually considered to be irreducible over $\mathbb Q[x]$ (if the coefficients are rational) and in this case, multiple roots are impossible since the complex numbers form a so-called perfect field.

Comment: I personnally feel that it is always important to highlight that the result is *much* stronger than "there is no general formula for quintics". It is rather "there are individual quintics for which there is no formula, and we can explicitly characterize them". Not only is there no general formula, but in most cases there is no formula *at all*, general or not.

Comment: Thanks Peter & Captain Lama.